# How to force emacs-style status-keys in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I have this problem with tmux 1.8: I want to set `status-keys` option to 'emacs' because I really dislike entering commands in vi-mode. However adding the following line to .tmux.conf has no effect:

```
set -g status-keys emacs
```

When tmux is restarted, `tmux show-options -g | grep keys` says `emacs` but the actual behaviour is vi-style.

The root of the problem is the `$EDITOR` environment variable, which it set to `vim` in my case. The documentations states:

```
status-keys [vi | emacs]
    Use vi or emacs-style key bindings in the status line,
    for example at the command prompt.  The default is emacs,
    unless the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables are set
    and contain the string `vi'.
```

So apparently when the environment variable is "vim" it forces vi status-keys.

Is there a way to override this behaviour and have the prompt behave emacs-style despite the environment variable? I can obviously hack around this (like starting tmux with other env variables and restoring the original later) but I hope there is a clean solution.

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone who found this thread while trying to figure out what `status-keys` does, note that this option was [removed](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/2.5/CHANGES#L97) in v2.5. (Though it has not been removed from its man page.)

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem and I think I just figured it out. Are you by chance also using ZSH (Z Shell)?

[I found this post](http://matija.suklje.name/zsh-vi-and-emacs-modes) that says that ZSH will also switch to "vi mode" if your VISUAL and/or EDITOR is set to vi/vim. So the problem I was having in tmux as actually bubbling up from ZSH!

In short, make sure you can use emacs-style keys in your shell outside of tmux. If you're using ZSH you can add `bindkey -e` to `.zshrc` to set emacs bindings. Then in `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g mode-keys emacs
set -g status-keys emacs
```

Comment: Solved my issue! Key bindings CTRL-a and CTRL-e would work in zsh, but no longer inside tmux session. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Both `status-key` and `mode-keys` default to `vi` if EDITOR contains `vi`, but this is *only* a default (during startup, before the configuration files are processed). Setting either of these options in your configuration should override the EDITOR-based default.

Are you also setting `mode-keys` (which controls the key maps used in `copy-mode`, and the `choose-…` commands)?

```
set -gw mode-keys emacs
```

Comment: I'm not setting `mode-keys` since I want it to be `vi`. However, unlike `status-keys`, when I do set `mode-keys` to `emacs` I get the correct overridden emacs behaviour. It appears that the issue only affects `status-keys`.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem with `EDITOR=vim tmux -L fresh -f /tmp/t` where `/tmp/t` contains just `set -g status-keys emacs`: the global `status-keys` is `emacs`, and I get Emacs-style bindings in the status line; the window-global `mode-keys` is `vi`, and I get vi-style bindings in `copy-mode`. Are that your session does not have its own value for `status-keys` that is overriding your global value? (Check that `tmux show-option | grep keys` gives no output.)

Comment: I did exactly what you described and I still have the problem. For now, I aliased `tmux` to `EDITOR= VISUAL= tmux` as a workaround.