# Keybindings send the wrong escape sequences

Tags: zsh, tmux

I use `tmux` with `zsh`, and all keybindings are broken. Example: `Ctrl-p` sends `^P`. I tried to add `setw -g xterm-keys on` in my `.tmux.conf` but that didn't solve the problem. I also tried to source the `.tmux.conf` file manually and to set the option directly from within `tmux` but that didn't do the trick either.

I could rebind all keys to their respective actions from `ZSH` (which I tried for `Ctrl-r` and it worked), but that's tedious...

I installed `tmux` (version `1.9_a-1`) and `zsh` (version `5.0.5`) using `pacman` in ArchLinux.

Is that a known bug? How can I solve the problem please?

Comment: What is the value of the `TERM` environment variable inside `tmux`? This sounds a bit like a terminal problem.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of managed to fix the problem by aliasing tmux to `EDITOR= VISUAL= tmux` (thanks to this comment: [How to force emacs-style status-keys in tmux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240683/how-to-force-emacs-style-status-keys-in-tmux#comment26798127_18247437)). But I still do not understand why I should do this. This seems like a bug...

Answer (score 0):

I use the following two options in my `~/.tmuxrc` and don't play any games with neither `EDITOR` nor `VISUAL`. That way I don't have to rely on the defaults but tell tmux explicitly which key emulation I want.

```
set -g mode-keys emacs
set -g status-keys emacs
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon the same issue. The problem is zsh; it's trying to be smart the same way as tmux.

My solution is to set the key binding to emacs while keeping EDITOR=vim.

```
export EDITOR='vim'
bindkey -e
```

References:

http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys

> Why isn't Control-R working (anymore)?
>
> You are probably in vi-Mode, because you have set $EDITOR or $VISUAL to something starting with
>   'vi'.

http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Keymaps

> If one of the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables contain the
>   string ‘vi’ when the shell starts up then it will be ‘viins’,
>   otherwise it will be ‘emacs’.

The `mode-keys` and `status-keys` options of tmux are for its own (copy/scroll mode and its command prompt )